# What is the correct way to remove property from node using Cypher?

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb

I have found two ways to remove the property from the node. The first one is `REMOVE n.name`, and the second one is `SET n.name= NULL`.

Is there a recommendation for which of these two methods is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually `REMOVE n.name` is preferred. `SET n.name = NULL` might be useful especially if the value (`null` in this case) is provided by parameter and you don't know if it will be `null` or some actual value.

More about: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/set/#set-remove-a-property